# Filename extraction with regex

Tags: regex

I need to be able to only extract the filename (info.txt) from a line like:

```
07/01/2010  07:25p                 953 info.txt
```

I've tried using this: `/d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+(?.?)`/, but it doesn't seem to work ...

Comment: Why on earth would you use a regex for this? What language is this?

Comment: \s means whitespace, not slash.

Comment: you need to explain what language you are using, not all RegEx is the same. Oh or just use `DIR /B` as Lars suggests.

Comment: One of my favorite regexes is `\\(^_^)/`. But it seldom does what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\d\d:\d\d\w\s+\d+\s+(.*?)$
```

`$1` will be the file name

The problem with your original regex is that it forgets the special characters `:`, `/`, and `(?.?)` means nothing...

Comment: this assumes time will end with p, rather than a or p.

Comment: I'm not familiar with whatever produces this output, but I changed that to `\w` just for you :)

Comment: You probably want another `\s+` or similar before the capturing group... otherwise $1 will be `" info.txt"` (leading space).

Comment: Thanks JV, this helped ... I'll accept within 30 secs (timer!).

Comment: JV, I actually get info.txt 953 info.txt, when I use this regex. I guess I'll play around since I'm prolly doing something wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you took arg 1? The whole return would be info.txt 953 info.txt, but arg 1 would be info.txt

Comment: I would expect the whole match to be `07:25p                 953 info.txt` (and agree that $1 should be `info.txt`).

Comment: Right yeah, +1, either way look at arg 1

Comment: Thanks for all your comments guys. I now have a better understanding of regex ...

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
/\S+$/
```

I.e. the longest possible string of non-whitespace at the end of the line.
(Hard to know for sure without more info about the possible inputs.)

As @J V pointed out, filenames with spaces in them (like his username) will not be parsed properly by the above regexp. We don't know from the question whether that's possible.

But I have a suspicion that we're looking at the output of Windows DIR command, or something very similar. In that case, the most reliable approach might be just to hack off the first 39 characters and keep the rest:

```
/^.{39}(.+)$/
```

Then `$1` will contain the filename.

### Better option:

But if you are using Windows DIR (as per your new comment), and you can control the DIR command, try

```
DIR /b
```

which removes the unneeded cruft (assuming you don't need the date, size etc.) and gives you one filename per line.

OK, you're using a Unix dir (per newer comment). The CentOS dir I have outputs one file per line, nothing else, when you give it no command line options. Chances are very good that whichever dir you're using can be persuaded to output filenames like that... then you wouldn't have to worry about using a regex that may or may not be correct for every possible input. Try `man dir` or `dir --help` to find out what command-line options to use.

Comment: @c0d3rs, can you define "doesn't...work"? What input did you use, what was the output, how did it differ from the expected output?

Comment: @J V, I think your point is that file names with spaces in them would get wrongly parsed by this regexp? Like I said, hard to know if this is acceptable, given the lack of info about possible inputs. I'll edit with another idea.

Comment: Hi Larsh : Aplogies! Yes, you are right, I am looking for the dir output. However, why would you restrict it to 39 characters? Sorry for not providing more information ...

Comment: @c0d3rs: "why would you restrict it to 39 characters?" A quick look at the Windows DIR output made me think that the definitive criterion for what is the filename was merely column number. I could be wrong, but didn't want to spend time looking up a spec when I didn't know for sure that you were using DIR output. Especially since you have "07:25a" in your sample output, while my Windows 7 box shows "07:25 AM". You may have to get more specific about the version of DIR you're using. **However an easier option would be to use `DIR /b`, which gets rid of all but the filenames.**

Comment: I see, LarsH. I'm using a unix machine and the dir/b doesn't work. I've figured out a way using regex though, thanks for bearing with my lack of information and still trying to help!

Comment: okay. You're using dir on unix. The dir command on my CentOS box, with no command-line options, gives the same output as `DIR /b` on Windows: one filename per line, nothing else. But there may be different flavors of dir; you might even be using a shell alias. If you try `which dir` and `man dir` you should be able to figure out how to make your dir output filenames only. But you already got a regex working so that's good.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the files have extension as .txt you can try.

```
  (?<=(\s)*)\w*.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use the following regex:

```
\w+\.\w+
```

Comment: Not all files have extensions, that's just a windows thing... Plus they can have numbers and special characters

Comment: No, that is not a Windows thing.

Comment: "In some operating systems (for example Unix) it is optional, while in some others (such as DOS) it is a requirement." - [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension) Ok, so not specifically a windows thing, but the only other OS' currently viable don't need it so :)

Comment: alright, let's not argue over something stupid like that. the pattern is flawed, I got it.

Comment: Files under Windows do not need an extension.

Comment: I would worry more about the missing backslash ;) And yeah they do, ever tried opening a file with an incorrect extension on windows?

Comment: @J V : Yes, I can open a file with an incorrect extension, by launching an application manually, then selecting File - Open and browsing to the file. What you mean is that files *that the user needs to be able to automatically launch an associated application to open them* need extensions.